# Compression of css is not working in Firefox and Iphone safari

Tags: css, .htaccess, compression

I Was using google page speed insights and it recommended my css pages to be compressed.So I added this htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
# Header set Content-Encoding compress
# Header set Content-Encoding x-gzip
</filesMatch>
```

So It was compressing css and working fine in chrome , But in firefox When I access http://fasttorrent.me/cdn/bootstrap.css css link it was blank and I get below error

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

So I added below code

```
<filesMatch "\.css$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-type "text/css"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

But still I get same error in firefox and iphone safari.

EDIT : I tried to set charset like below..still error

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|css|js)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: The error complains about the character set, not the MIME type.

Comment: how can I define character set

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem earlier and it looks like firefox doesn't support the following lines because they are declaring that the output is compressed but not actually compressing it. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1063554

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
# Header set Content-Encoding compress
# Header set Content-Encoding x-gzip
</filesMatch>
```

So as per this link https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html I replaced it with the following and now all seems to be working.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```